# Does a SQL Server database need a backup device to backup database?

Tags: sql-server-2014, database-backups

I am currently looking at database and log backups on our work SQL Servers however I am very new to SQL Server backups.

I have been told that the SQL Servers are being backed-up by an external company. On each server U have run the below query and it shows the backups.

```
   SELECT  
CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,  
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,  
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
CASE msdb..backupset.type  
WHEN 'D' THEN 'Database'  
WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'  
END AS backup_type,  
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size,  
msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,  
msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,   
msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.description 
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily  
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id =    msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
WHERE  (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) >= GETDATE() - 1)  
ORDER BY  
msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, 
msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date
```

However I have been reading up on SQL Server backups and backup devices so I wanted to check if the SQL servers we have have any. I used the script below to check and it returned nothing.

```
select * from sys.backup_devices
```

Could I get some advice on whether it is ok that no backup devices are showing or should it have returned something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a helpful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addumpdevice-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  See relevant screenshot below - essentially, adding an entry to sys.backup_devices just allows you to refer to the backup disk by a logical name, instead of browsing to it or specifying a full filepath when programmatically backing up.

[image: from Microsoft:]